# Unknown system variable 'show_compatibility_56'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I like backupninja because of simplicity. Unfortunately it started giving me this problem:

> Warning: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */
>   dead.letter FROM `GLOBAL_STATUS`': The
>   'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS' feature is disabled; see the
>   documentation for 'show_compatibility_56' (3167)

It looks like this can be fixed with `set @@global.show_compatibility_56=ON`. Unfortunately that doesn't work on my MariaDB instance:

> Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your
>   MariaDB connection id is 73 Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
>   Debian 9.1
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.
>
> MariaDB [(none)]> set @@global.show_compatibility_56=ON;
>   ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'show_compatibility_56'

What else can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://support.servosity.com/hc/en-us/articles/221071687-ISSUE-The-INFORMATION-SCHEMA-GLOBAL-STATUS-feature-is-disabled-see-the-documentation-for-show-compatibility-56-

Comment: Sounds like `backupninja` was not written with MariadDB in mind.  Can you see what commands it generated?  Maybe you can/should abandon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [fixed](https://0xacab.org/riseuplabs/backupninja/commit/711ea76dd11ff4f5c73ca5dd6721f40d973704c2) so a later version (>1.0.2) of `backupninja` will likely resolve your issue.